# Add month and date to year as SQL parameter

Tags: sql, parameters, optional-parameters

I need to be able to add the month and day to the year for the parameter.

Since our fiscal year starts on July 1st each year, I need to make it so that users can type in the fiscal year 'YYYY' as the parameter and it will return results from the fiscal starting the July 1st the year before that year began and end the July 1st of that year.

For example.  For fiscal year 2016, I would need all records that end after July 1, 2015 and start before June 30, 2016.  Currently users have to remember to Specify July 1st and June 30.  How can I make it so they can just type in the year?

Currently works but requires full date as the parameter

```
Where (E.end_date > @param1 Or E.end_date Is Null Or @param1 Is Null) And
  (E.start_date < @param2 Or e.start_date Is Null Or @param2 Is Null)
```

But this won't work

```
Where (A.end_date > @param1 Or A.end_date Is Null Or @param1 Is Null) And
    (A.start_date < DateAdd(day, 1, @param2) Or A.start_date Is Null Or
      @param2 Is Null)
      And
      (A.end_date > dateadd(yyyy,-1,'@param3-07-01') And
    A.start_date < '@param3-07-01' Or @param3 Is Null)
```

SQL, at least in the widget they give me to input SQL into for our records software, doesn't like the syntax of `'@param3-07-01'` putting a parameter in a date string for evaluation for a date, but it will accept `'2016-07-01'` will allow other situations where I put parameters inside strings in a where clause, such as `Like '%@param1%'`

Comment: Which SQL server do you use?

Comment: ]From the Vendor: Credible does not share this information as it is proprietary, however I checked with our IT department and found that if the query you are writing is standard SQL then it will run. If you have any additional questions, please let me know."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at this backward.  The solution was not to convert the year parameter into a date, but to convert the date into a year.

```
year(dateAdd(mm,6,A.start_date))
year(dateAdd(mm,6,A.end_date))
```

I plugged that into my code and it worked great.

```
Where (year(dateAdd(mm,6,A.end_date)) > @param1 Or A.end_date Is Null Or @param1 Is Null) And
    (year(dateAdd(mm,6,A.start_date)) < DateAdd(day, 1, @param2) Or A.start_date Is Null Or @param2 Is Null)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be taking the year Parameter as a string and concatenating the date as a string literal. Then, we could use Data Type Conversion functions to convert dates

**For instance:**

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '23-10-2016', 105) -- dd-mm-yyyy
```